# Как упорядочить рандомные setTimeout

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Как сделать так, чтобы гарантировано вывело в консоль A, B, C.
Править функции нельзя.

```
function A() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('A')
  }, Math.random()*100)
}

function B() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('B')
  }, Math.random()*100)
}

function C() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('C')
  }, Math.random()*100)
}
```

Comment: если править функции нельзя - то никак.

Comment: @Grundy, почему нельзя, можно из вызвать в разное время)))

Comment: @Leonid только если время в функциях реально всегда будут *100 а не скажем *300 в функции B

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, менять функции нельзя, но смотреть то можно... Значит надо будет установить по максимальному разбросу для гарантии.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот решение через Promise

```js
function A() {
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('A')
            resolve();
          }, Math.random()*100)
    });
    
}

function B() {
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('B')
            resolve();
          }, Math.random()*100)
    });
    
}

function C() {
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('C')
            resolve();
          }, Math.random()*100)
    });
    
}
async function start(){
    await A();
    await B();
    C();

}
start();
```

Если есть какие-то вопросы спрашивайте.

Comment: не совсем так, изменять функции нельзя

Comment: @АртёмМолчанов так не меняйте функции - напишите свои асинхронные и вызовите исходные из них

Answer (score 1):

Для того, что бы гарантированно получить A,B,C можно по очереди вызвать каждую функцию в разное время, учитывая предельно возможную девиацию выполнения каждой из них.

```js
[A,B,C].forEach((f,i) => {setTimeout(() => {f()}, i*100)});

function A() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('A')
}, Math.random()*100)
}

function B() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('B')
}, Math.random()*100)
}

function C() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('C')
}, Math.random()*100)
}
```